# When importing Swift class into Obj-C: Property not found on object of type

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm creating an iOS app that communicates with a peripheral device via Bluetooth. The Bluetooth device's API is written in Objective-C, so I chose to write my AppDelegate and ViewController are written in Objective-C as well. I also developed a CoreML algorithm, which I chose to interact with that model from Swift (XCode autogenerate a Swift class named `Model` for me).  From there, I created a second Swift class named `Predictor`, which has a method called `predict` that returned the result of the ML algorithm contained in `Model.`  However, when I imported the `Predictor` Swift class to my Objective-C view controller, XCode couldn't seem to access its `predict` method.

I am new to Objective-C and Swift, but I think I have a concrete understanding of class structures. I have tried so many things that at this point, I'm just guessing.  I must have a fundamental misunderstanding of Swift/Objective-C, but I cannot identify it.

My Predictor class in Swift is exposed to Objective-C and inherits from NSObject, but does not have an init() function (I do not believe one is necessary?).

```
@objcMembers class Predictor: NSObject {

    let model = Model();

    @objc func predict(data: [Double]) -> Int64 {
        isPreictal = model.prediction(input: data)
        return isPreictal.classLabel
    }
}
```

ViewController.h

```
@class Predictor;
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
< IXNMuseConnectionListener, IXNMuseDataListener, IXNMuseListener, IXNLogListener>
- (IBAction)compute:(id)sender;
- (Predictor *)returnSwiftObject;
- (void)applicationWillResignActive;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SeizureSense-Swift.h"

@interface SimpleController () <CBCentralManagerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) Predictor * myModel;

double modelInputs[30];

- (void)viewDidLoad { _myModel = [Predictor new]; }

- (IBAction)compute:(id)sender {
    [self log:@"%d", _myModel.predict(data: modelInputs)];
}
@end
```

Seeing as my Swift class `Predictor` is imported to ViewController.h and my SeizureSense-Swift header is imported to ViewController.m, I would expect that I could access the `predict` method inside of `Predictor` class instance `myModel`, but the following error message is returned: `Property 'predict' not found on object of type 'Predictor *'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_myModel.predict(data: modelInputs)` cannot work. You are trying to use Swift syntax in Objective-C.

In Objective-C syntax for calling methods is different. Actually, even the method names are different. Your call should be something like:

```
[self log:@"%d", [_myModel predictWithData:modelInputs]];
```

Comment: Thanks Sulthan for your polite, simple, and speedy response. You certainly have solved my issue of using Swift syntax in Objective C. However, my code now returns the following error: ```No visible @interface for 'Predictor' declares the selector 'predict'``` (this also applies for selectors ```predictData``` and ```predictdata```. I did describe the 'predict' method inside of my 'Predictor' class... Perhaps the method name in Objective-C is just different?

Comment: @MatthewAnderson Where are you using `predict`? I used `predictData` because that's how Swift function `predict(data:)` will be transformed. Also note that the function in `Swift` should be probably `public`.

Comment: I tested the use of both selectors, ```predict``` and ```predictData```. Moreover, I changed my Swift class ```Predictor``` and function ```predict``` to ```public```. I believe I did import the Swift header properly to ```ViewController.m``` via ```#import "SeizureSense-Swift.h"```, which matches with my Objective-C Generated Interface Name in build settings.  I am still facing an error: ```No visible @interface for 'Predictor' declares the selector 'predictData'```

Comment: @MatthewAnderson That's strange. You should have code completion on `predictor` anyway, after typing `[_myModel`

Comment: Looks like ```predict(data:)``` would be transformed to ```predictWithData``` instead of ```predictData```.

Comment: Oh, that's certainly possible :) btw, you can control the name using `@objc(predictData)` if you want to change it.